# Java Assertions : How to assert for 2 fields on same value

Tags: java, junit

In my code, I have to assert one value against 2 fields. This is what I have to do :

```
assertThat(request.get(0).name()).isEqualTo("ABC");
assertThat(request.get(0).name2()).isEqualTo("ABC");
```

How can I use one single line assertion for the above 2 lines?

For example to explain more what I need :

Is there a way I can achieve something like :

```
assertThat(request.get(0).name() && request.get(0).name2()).isEqualTo("ABC");
```

Comment: My question is different to what is asked in the link.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I use one single line assertion for the above 2 lines?

Why do you want to do such a thing ?

By trying to try too clever, you will get two drawbacks :

- you will make your test more complex to read and to maintain.
- you will lose the relevant feedback information as a test fails

Actually your test is fine.
If any of these two values doesn't respect the assertion, you have the exact line that spots the issue and you also have a relevant information message.

As a hint, you could maybe just remove the duplication :

```
final String expected = "ABC";
assertThat(request.get(0).name()).isEqualTo(expected);
assertThat(request.get(0).name2()).isEqualTo(expected);
```

I don't want to say that it is bad to make multiple assertions in a same statement.
 Not at all.
I say only that you have to adapt your way of asserting to the tools you are using.
And about it, you don't specify the matcher tool.
If the matcher tool provides a support to make this kind of assertion, use it.
Otherwise, don't make it in a raw way otherwise you will lose the benefit of getting useful failure test messages.

---

Here is an example with AssertJ that provides this feature out of box.

```
@Test
void namesEquals() {
    List<Request> requests = new ArrayList<>();
    requests.add(new Request("ABC", "ABD"));
    Assertions.assertThat(requests.get(0)).extracting(Request::name, Request::name2)
                                          .containsExactly("ABC", "ABC");
}
```

And in this failing test, you will get a useful information message :

> java.lang.AssertionError:
>
> Expecting:
>
> <["ABC", "ABD"]>
>
> to contain exactly (and in same order):
>
> <["ABC", "ABC"]>
>
> but some elements were not found:
>
> <[]>
>
> and others were not expected:
>
> <["ABD"]>

Comment: This should be accepted as the right answer

Answer (score 2):

A bit too clever perhaps, but you can try this:

```
assertTrue(Stream.of(request.get(0).name(), request.get(0).name2())
        .allMatch("ABC"::equals));
```

Or you can give this a spin:

```
assertThat(Arrays.asList(request.get(0).name(), request.get(0).name2()),
        Every.everyItem(IsEqual.equalTo("ABC")));
```

Answer (score 0):

something like:

```
assertThat(request.get(0).name().equals( request.get(0).name2()) ? 
                       request.get(0).name() : "false").isEqualTo("ABC");
```